# Change input value on change dropdown

Tags: octobercms

In creating section (New Record) when I select hotel room from dropdown I want to output price of selected room to another input.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Where did you find hotel room? What do you mean?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you will need to use dependsOn field property.

```
hotel_room:
    label: Hotel Room
    type: dropdown

price:
    label: Price
    type: text
    dependsOn: hotel_room
```

Now whenever you will select a value from hotel_room dropdown then below method will be called on attached model in which you can set the value of price field.

```
public function filterFields($fields, $context = null)
{
    if (isset($fields->price)) {

        //Write your logic here to get Hotel Price value by hotel id
        $hotel_price = 25//For example
        $fields->price->value = $hotel_price;
    }
}
```

Let me know if you need more help ?